# Notification in django?

Tags: python, django

I have been developing in django for sometime now, and have developed a neat website having functionality such as writing blogs, posting questions, sharing content etc. However there is still one thing that is missing and i.e. creating notification for users.

What I want to do is to inform users in their profiles, whenever somebody comments on their posts, or if they are following a particular post and there is an update on it, then inform the user of that update. I have looked around many applications but I am still very confused about how to do it.

In case of using django-notification I seem to have an impression(which can be wrong) that I can use this only to inform the user via email, i.e. I cannot show these notifications in the user profile, just like we have on facebook.

Firstly I would like to know if I am wrong, and then I really need some proper tutorial or guidance on how to go about doing it. I know how to register a notification and send it on proper signal but there is no documentation on how to show these notices in a template, if this can be done.

Any guidance/tutorial/getting started doc will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Websockets are simple and very useful in terms of bi-directional communication between clients and servers. If your app's features list grows it will be possible that you will need additional events in your app. WS will help you to scale.